# Disable or overlay link inside Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, overlay

```js
var iframe = document.querySelector('#iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('src', 'https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/20db63b8-999b-4f26-8819-b3f11e034535/page/VgD');
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  resize: both;
  /* pointer-events: none; */
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <iframe id="iframe" src=""></iframe>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

How to hide URL and make it unable to open this report from iframe dialog. Is it possible to hide or overlay with dev particular button("Google Studio danych") and make it unclickable?

Please check here:
https://jsfiddle.net/k53p2xdb/
[image]

Comment: You can cover that link up but if a user really wants to find the link they can e.g. by removing your cover in browser dev tools. So it depends on how important it is to stop them clicking there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can write CSS for inside of iframe, but i find a workaround for you.

Wrap your iframe in a container and create black overlay outside of iframe, I just update the changes in below code snippet. I hope it'll help you out. Thank You

[image]

```js
var iframe = document.querySelector('#iframe'); 
iframe.setAttribute('src', 'https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/20db63b8-999b-4f26-8819-b3f11e034535/page/VgD');
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px; 
  width: 400px; 
}

.overlay {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 24px;
  width: 100%
}


iframe { 
  height: 100%;
  resize: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html> 
  <body> 
    <div class="parent">
      <iframe id="iframe" src=""></iframe>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
      <script src="main.js"></script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Best solution so far!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can try it => https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_element_iframe